# Keycloak user data encoding

Tags: encoding, wildfly, keycloak

By default users' data fields (e.g. first name and last name) are encoded using ISO-8859-1. People from many countries can't properly create accounts as their personal data is silently messed up. How can I fix it?

- The DB receives already damaged names. By default all columns are ISO-8859-1-encoded, but converting them to UTF-8 doesn't help.
- Manual account modification from admin console has same effect.
- Change of default server (Wildfly) encoding to UTF-8 doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out, that it's a bug involving connection with MySQL, you can follow it on [Keycloak Jira](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-3439).

Answer (score 0):

The [KEYCLOAK-3259](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-3259) bug states, that the encoding of the forms depends on the default encoding of the JVM. This will be fixed in Keycloak 
2.1.0.CR1.

Did you try to change the JVM default encoding by passing `-Dfile.encoding=UTF8` to the Java commandline or Java options?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried it before by modifying standalone.xml using CLI and now with the JVM flags, but failed twice.